# Can git log show all branches reachable from a given commit?

Tags: git

Git log normally shows a given commit and its ancestors. I'm interested in seeing the *descendants* of a given commit (or branch pointer).
In other words, for all possible branches, show only those which contain the given commit.
Is there anything simpler than

```bash
git log --graph $(git branch --contains COMMIT_ID --format='%(objectname)')
```

?

Comment: That doesn't seem so bad. Turn it into a git alias and you'll only ever have to type it once...

Comment: `log-from = "!f() { git log --graph $(git branch --all --contains \"$1\" --format='%(objectname)') \"^${1}~\"; }; f"`